# Logging when limit Exceeds

Tags: linux, security, logs

Is there a log file that logs information when the values set in `/etc/security/limits.conf` are exceeded?

If not is there a way to make it log when the values are exceeded?

Answer (score 3):

There is no central log for every process that hits these limits.

Whenever a process tries to allocate resources which exceed it's limit, it receives a negative return code from the OS, so each process can handle this case in it's own way. Most processes will write something into their specific log if they hit one of the limits, but you'll have to check that for each process specifically.

Comment: Processes may also end up being killed. Note that you can log syscalls that fail with a given errno with the audit system, so you can use it for some limits that cause syscalls to fail with a specific errno.

Answer (score 3):

As per man limit page

> The pam_limits module does report configuration problems found in its
>   configuration file and errors via syslog(3).

So you need to define as below

```
pam_limits.so [ conf=/path/to/limits.conf ] [ debug ] [ set_all ] [ utmp_early ] [ noaudit ]
```

Example of my `/etc/pam.d/su`

```
session    required   pam_limits.so conf=/etc/security/limits.conf
```

Reference Link
[pam_limits - limit resources](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_limits.html)
[man page limits.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question though.

Comment: yes sir, I have also configure the same and tested with open file limit 50, but it doesn't shows anything in logs

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to achieve partial solution using **audit subsystem**. The idea is to track the failed system calls.

You may refer [1] to track the work I have done in this field.

[1] https://github.com/PaulDaviesC/Logging-limits.conf